# Cannot Uninstall IoT Edge on Windows Server

Tags: powershell, azure-iot-edge

I need to swap an IoT Edge device on Windows from one IoT Hub to another. I understand that current logic forces me to Uninstall IoT-Edge and install it again.
The problem is I get the following error trying to run this script:

```
{Invoke-WebRequest -useb aka.ms/iotedge-win} | Invoke-Expression; `
Uninstall-IoTEdge
```

I get this in return:

[image]

```
Invoke-Native : The term 'cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1748 char:28
+ ... ersString = Invoke-Native "$dockerExe ps --all --format ""{{.ID}}"""  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cmd:String) [Invoke-Native], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Invoke-Native
```

The Powershell is elevated as Admin. Am my missing some PATH variables? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

would you please run below commands in PowerShell window and share the results?

1. Get-Command "docker.exe"
2. Write-Host $env:ProgramFiles\iotedge-moby
   check if the path exists or not.
3. do you know which version of iotedge service you installed? if the service is running, you can run "iotedge version" to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, but did manage to find workaround by removing docker with the help of this script:

https://success.docker.com/article/how-to-completely-remove-docker-in-windows-10

As fas as IOT Edge version it is 1.0.7 as 1.0.8. does not work in transparent gateway mode with Node-Red MQTT node (MS advised to wait for 1.0.9 where this bug will be fixed).